# Learning the Structure of a Hierarchical Reinforcement Task

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I've been studying hierachial reinforcement learning problems, and while a lot of papers propose interesting ways for learning a policy, they all seem to assume they know in advance a graph structure describing the actions in the domain. For example, [The MAXQ Method for Hierarchial Reinforcement Learning](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.9.313&rep=rep1&type=ps) by Dietterich describes a complex graph of actions and sub-tasks for a simple Taxi domain, but not how this graph was discovered. How would you learn the hierarchy of this graph, and not just the policy?

Comment: You could also try posting your question here


  : http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Could we have some more idea about the scenario for which you want to learn the hierarchical reinforcement structure? Or is this a general question?

Comment: @Amit, It's a general question. To use the paper's example, if a Taxi were wondering around aimlessly, with no prior knowledge of the world, and only the primitive move-left,move-right,etc actions to take, how would it learn higher level actions like go-to-pick-up-passenger? If I'm understanding the paper correctly (and I may not be), it proposes how to update the policy for the high-level actions, but not how they're formed to begin with.

Comment: @Chris The topic you are talking about might be classified under hierarchy learning for AI Planning. A related paper is http://www.aaai.org/Papers/JAIR/Vol26/JAIR-2606.pdf (but this is not specifically for hierarchy learning). This paper assumes that a set of primitive actions is provided beforehand (just like move-left etc you mention). This topic is advanced -- for basics of AI Planning refer to Russell and Norvig's book for example.

Comment: I'm a bit late to this party, but you'll find some good stuff if you search for automatic induction (or discovery) of MAXQ hierarchies.  A bunch of people are doing work in this area.

Comment: @Nate, Thanks, that's definitely the topic I'm looking for. Are you aware of any published source code implementing any of these algorithms? I'm only finding research papers through Google, and none of them describe the algorithms in enough detail for me to implement them myself.

Comment: @Chris, I haven't heard of anything that's been officially released, but I'm sure that software exists in some form.  If you ask nicely, you might be able to get one of the authors of those papers to send you some code -- focus on asking grad students, not profs, though.

Comment: After getting very creative with my Google searches, I finally found http://www.igi.tugraz.at/ril-toolbox/general/overview.html. It appears to be the result of a Master's thesis, is written in C++, and hasn't been maintained in 4 years, but seems to contain a hierarchical reinforcement learning example using the Taxi domain. I can't determine what specific algorithm it's using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dietterich's MAXQ, the graph is constructed manually. It's considered to be a task for the system designer, in the same way that coming up with a representation space and reward functions are.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you might want to automatically decompose the state space, learn relevant features, or transfer experience from simple tasks to more complex ones.

I'd suggest you just start reading papers that refer to the MAXQ one you linked to. Without knowing what exactly what you want to achieve, I can't be very prescriptive (and I'm not really on top of all the current RL research), but you might find relevant ideas in the work of Luo, Bell & McCollum  or the papers by Madden & Howley.

Answer (score 1):

This paper describes one approach that is a good starting point:

N. Mehta, S. Ray, P. Tadepalli, and T. Dietterich. Automatic Discovery and Transfer of MAXQ Hierarchies. In International Conference on Machine Learning, 2008.

http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~mehtane/papers/hi-mat.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Say there is this agent out there moving about doing things. You don't know its internal goals (task graph). How do you infer its goals?

In way way, this is impossible. Just as it is impossible for me to know what goal you had mind when you put that box down: maybe you were tired, maybe you saw a killer bee, maybe you had to pee....

You are trying to model an agent's internal goal structure. In order to do that you need some sort of guidance as to what are the set of possible goals and how these are represented by actions. In the research literature this problem has been studied under the terms "plan recognition" and also with the use of POMDP (partially observable markov decision process), but both of these techniques assume you do know something about the other agent's goals.

If you don't know anything about its goals, all you can do is either infer one of the above models (This is what we humans do. I assume others have the same goals I do. I never think, "Oh, he dropped his laptop, he must be ready to lay an egg" cse, he's a human.) or model it as a black box: a simple state-to-actions function then add internal states as needed (hmmmm, someone must have written a paper on this, but I don't know who).

Comment: In the problem I'm referring to, the agent doesn't have any interal goals yet. I'm asking how does the agent learn the hierarchy of it goals and subgoals. In the paper I mention, this hierarchy is predefined. If it weren't predefined, and the agent could only perform primitive actions, how would it learn a hierarchy to speed up it's planning and learning?

Comment: Ah, so, you mean how do you write an agent that learns higher-level concepts, like "pickup closest passenger"...that's tough. The problem reminds of work by the SOAR group on "chunking" and the fields of cased-based reasoning and explanation-based learning (but they still also require a domain theory).